# Is there any way to remotely control a surface tablet running Windows 10 in kiosk mode

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, kiosk

We are planning to put a surface tablet at a client site, and put it in kiosk mode using Windows 10 Assigned Access, and that part works well.

Edited: This is a Windows 10 Home version, so there is no RDP on it.

However, in case there is any software or hardware issues, we would like to be able to "remote into" (Bomgar, etc.) the surface tablet, and be able to diagnose the issues, and put it back in kiosk mode when we are done. Also, we may need to do regular maintenance like running Windows security updates...
Is there any way we can manage this remotely?  Any advice?

Comment: Depending on the Surface you buy it will come with Windows 10 Pro, which has RDP, it just needs to be configured.

Comment: Sorry for not knowing much about this, does this mean if it runs Windows 10 Pro, we should be able to access it using RDP even if it's currently running in the kiosk mode? If so, do you know when we RDP in, would it turn off the kiosk mode, and whether we can turn it back to kiosk mode when we disconnect from RDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post
[Windows 10 Pro - 1511 - Assigned Access for Remote Desktop App](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1daae24d-6135-455f-b200-5b40b25e4fe9/windows-10-pro-1511-assigned-access-for-remote-desktop-app?forum=win10itprogeneral)
contains an answer by a Microsoft person om how to enable RDP in Kiosk mode,
which apparently didn't work well. I reproduce it here:

> 1. Open PowerShell as elevated
> 2. Run command
>
>    ```
>    Set-AssignedAccess -UserName <assigned access account name> -AppUserModelId Microsoft.RemoteDesktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
>    ```

Since RDP seems to be troublesome under Assigned Access, you might use a
third-party product.

From the thread
[Touch screen not responding sometimes in assigned access](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a01d6ac-9f26-4f5b-a37b-3f8e39c1c423/touch-screen-not-responding-sometimes-in-assigned-access?forum=Offtopic)
the interesting part for you is that TeamViewer, a VNC variant, still
works in this mode.
TeamViewer is only
[Free for Personal Use](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/credentials/free-for-personal-use/),
but other free 
[VNC variants](https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/?license=free)
exist which you can try.

Comment: Thank you, @harrymc. Since RDP isn't a reliable option at this point anyway, maybe we shouldn't bother to go with Windows 10 Pro, and the Home edition works just fine. We will try some of the VNC variant, and see how it will work for us.